# How to display strings instead of numbers in scatter plot axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

i want to change this in a way that the x axis shows string instead of numeric values.

```
chart1.width(500)
    .height(500)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 30])) //This reflect the number.. how do i change it to show string instead?
    .yAxisLabel("ID")
    .xAxisLabel("Stage")
    .clipPadding(10)
    .dimension(dim1)
    .excludedOpacity(0.5)
    .group(group1);
```

Comment: You can try using an ordinal x scale [but there may be issues with that](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1135).